# Property 'selection' does not exist on type 'IGridInstanceOf<any>' when executing gridApi.grid.selection.selectAll

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, ui-grid

I am trying to use gridApi.grid.selection.selectAll option to check/select 'selectAll' checkbox in uiGrid header programmatically. But it throws the below error:

**Property 'selection' does not exist on type 'IGridInstanceOf'.**

I am using angular ui-grid typings file and I don't find the 'selectAll' option in the file. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The correct call would be:

```
gridApi.selection.selectAllRows
```

gridApi.grid doesn't have the "selection" method:

[image]

On the other hand, gridApi.selection has:

[image]

For reference: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi

Edit #1

To desselect the rows, you can use:

```
gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows(); //For all rows
gridApi.selection.unSelectRow(rowEntity); //For one row (You need to pass the rowEntity)
```

Comment: gridApi.selection.selectAllRows() works to select the 'select All' checkbox programatically. Is there anyway to uncheck it?

Comment: I tried using gridApi.selection.unSelectRow(rowEntity). It unselected that row but did not clear the 'select All' checkbox.

Comment: Well, that will depend on what you're using as model on your "select all" checkbox
Can you provide some code?